# Random walk with shifted exponential increment. How to calculate hitting time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Suppose $\{X_i, i=1,2,\cdots\}$ are random variables are i.i.d. from standard exponential distribution.

Define the random walk as:
$$S_0=0,$$
$$S_{i+1}=\max\{0,S_i+X_i-k\},$$
where $k>1$.

Then how can we calculate the average hitting time of this process? In other words, how to calculate
$$E[T(h)]=E[\inf_i{X_i\ge h}].$$

In addition, how to calculate the expected hitting time of a random process bounded below but has increments with a negative expectation.

Thank you.

Comment: Your writing of $T(h)$ seems to imply that it is determinstic, where the hitting time is usually itself a random variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've changed to the expectation of the hitting time.